# Configure Internet Explorer so username omitted from cookies

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I modified the registry so that All users cookies are being stored in the same location.

Once you have more than one user Windows puts your Windows username on the front of the file name of each cookie downloaded by that user.

I want users to share a specific cookie.

I am running Server 2008 R2 but I believe this can be done the same way on Windows 7, Vista, XP, & 2003.

How do I remove the prefix on cookies?  I was looking in the registry and I found this:

Internet Settings, 5.0, Cache, Cookies:     PerUserItem

The key has a value of @User

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"EmailName"="User@"

I emptied all these keys but it did not work.

Comment: I know I am swimming against the tide but that doesnt mean it can't be done.  In fact windows does it by default.  It only puts the %username$@ prefix on the cookies after you have more than one user account on that system.

Comment: I would refrain from using your application if I knew you were mucking with cookies in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you're swimming against the tide, or at least I hope you are. Cookies are not meant to be shared between users.

Answer (score 0):

That won't be possible.  The registry has a separate user-specific hive for each user.

What are you trying to accomplish with this?  Maybe you should not have individual users, only a single account for all users to use.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way about 2 hours after posting here.  Thanks for the quick responses even if some were just to tell me I was swimming against the current.  Nothing I don't already know, its the only way I know how to swim.  Anyway for those of you interested this is what I did:

I changed the command line path of internet explorer using the runas command.
c:\windows\system32\runas.exe /savecred /user:username "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

The runas command allows you to run a program as a different user, for example if you need to give that program adminstrative access but you dont want to make your user an administrator.  Now IE is running under the same user although people log into my server under different names.

The reason I was trying to do this was to defeat a protection on a website which limits how many uses I can run at once.  Now they just think i have one user logged in!